# Retrieve a class text python selenium and iterate all pages

Tags: python, html, selenium

I tried to retrieve the MFR number of items of EPSON from a website.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome( "C:\All\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" )
driver.get('https://shop.techdata.com/searchall?b=1&kw=printer')
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name( 'productDetailsLink' )

for i, item in enumerate(items):
    if 'EPSON' in item.text:
        MFR= item.find_element_by_xpath( './/span[@class = "darkTxt"]')
        print (i, item.text,MFR)
```

I retrieved 'i' correctly but something is going wrong with MFR for EPSON products only and I cannot retrieve the MFR. I am getting an error saying no element was found in MFR. Next I want to go to next page and retrieve MFR of EPSON there also. I cannot do that.

Error

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//span[@class = "darkTxt"]"}
```

I am a newbie so please help me! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are finding link as a Parent Element, if you will see the html Code, Link doesn't have any child element.

You need to find whole Div which contains all the information as Parent Element. which has following HTML code

```html
<div class="productResult js-productResult unpriced needsLogin">
```

Following code snippet will work with just one minor change about parent element.

```
driver.get('https://shop.techdata.com/searchall?b=1&kw=printer')
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('productResult')

    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        if 'EPSON' in item.text:
            MFR = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "darkTxt"]')
            print (i, item.text, MFR)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked but it is retrieving all numbers(TDI, MFR,Price) I want only MFR. Can you please tell me how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome( "C:\All\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe" )
driver.get('https://shop.techdata.com/searchall?b=1&kw=printer')
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name( 'productResult' )

for i, item in enumerate(items):

if 'EPSON' in item.text:


    MFR= item.find_element_by_xpath( './/div[@class = "productCodes"]/div[2]/span')
    print (i, item.text,MFR)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked but it is retrieving all numbers(TDI, MFR,Price) I want only MFR. Can you please tell  me how do I do that?

Comment: Thanks. It worked but it is retrieving all numbers(TDI, MFR,Price) I want only MFR. Can you please tell  me how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Chromium but it looks to me just a typo, no starting dot on the path to `find_element_by_xpath`:

```
MFR= item.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class = "darkTxt"]')
print (i, item.text, MFR)
```